# Group a collection and return a Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq, refactoring

I've written a method that takes a collection of items (price items - each item has an amount and a code) and groups them by code then returns an IDictionary where the key is the code of the item and the value is the group of items with that code (Hope that makes sense!)

Here's the implementation of the method:

```cs
public IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<PriceDetail>> GetGroupedPriceDetails(IEnumerable<PriceDetail> priceDetails)
{
    // create a dictionary to return
    var groupedPriceDetails = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<PriceDetail>>();

    // group the price details by code
    var grouping = priceDetails.GroupBy(priceDetail => priceDetail.Code);

    // foreach grouping, add the code as key and collection as value to the dictionary
    foreach (var group in grouping)
    {
        groupedPriceDetails.Add(group.Key, group);
    }

    // return the collection
    return groupedPriceDetails;
}
```

I then tried to refactor this to use ToDictionary like so:

```cs
// group the price details by code and return
return priceDetails.GroupBy(priceDetail => priceDetail.Code)
                   .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group);
```

I get an error when I try to compile which says I can't convert from a dictionary of `string, IGrouping<string, PriceDetail>` into a dictionary of `string, IEnumerable<PriceDetail>`.

Can someone tell me how to correctly refactor my first attempt at this method?  I feel that there's a more concise way of writting it but can't figure it out!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about:

```
public ILookup<string, PriceDetail> GetGroupedPriceDetails(IEnumerable<PriceDetail> priceDetails)
{
     return priceDetails.ToLookup(priceDetail => priceDetail.Code);
}
```

Comment: I want the collection returned to be keyed by code, and the value for each key should be the collection of PriceDetails for that code - so <string, IEnumerable<PriceDetail>>.  Can I do that with your method?

Comment: If you are transforming into a dictionary just for the ability to search for a code and get a collection, with no intention to further modify the dictionary, ILookup is a better match.

Comment: The next in the process after I've returned from this method is to iterate through the collection (so, for each group) and sum the amount of the collection of price details for that group.  Am I missing something here?  Can I do that using ILookup instead?  Or, now that I'm writing this, I'm thinking I should return something that has the code as a key and then an amount which is the sum and do it all in one method... any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: OK cool - I had no idea what ILookup was doing so I had a read and found it extends IGrouping etc etc.  Just implemented the change and ran a test to see what comes back and it's exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 91):

Can you not do:

```
priceDetails.GroupBy(priceDetail => priceDetail.Code)
               .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList())
```

Comment: i feel like this is the answer

Comment: This is what I've been looking for